# Debugging Issues (Android Eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am having a problem where when I switch to DDMS view and look at the Logcat, everything is yellow. All lines are yellow and Time, PID, Application, and Tag all display question marks for every line. This makes the Logcat useless and makes it incredibly hard to debug. In the past everything has worked fine and I am not sure why this has started happening.

I am using a Verizon Galaxy Nexus with a 4.1 build (could be the problem?).

I am also a beginner (probably excruciatingly obvious).

Thanks for any help.

SOLVED: Apparently I had to update eclipse and the SDK (i feel dumb). Thanks to everyone who spent time tying to help me out.

(It won't let me answer my own question because i am new)

Comment: Hey Topsnus, what is the little dropdown in the upper right corner say? Default is verbose. It is right next to the floppy-disk save icon.

Comment: It says verbose, but changing it to anything else doesn't help.

Comment: Have you tried restarting eclipse?

Comment: The solution provided by @Revolutionair is correct. I faced the same thing and then I updated my eclipse and the ADT. it worked then

Answer (score 31):

Updating your Eclipse and Android SDK will likely solve the problem.

Here's a screenshot, I have lived this too.

[image: screenie]

I'm just posting this so you could mark it as an answer for people who may have encountered this situation too.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have your filter set to "warn". Make sure that it is set to "verbose" and make that you don't have any other filters on. If you do, on the left you highlight "All Messages" and don't have any other filters set.

Comment: I have checked this and it is set to verbose. Here is an image if it helps: http://imageshack.us/f/816/captureyl.png/

Comment: It does help! It looks like its debugging, but rather than separating the files, they are all being lumped together in the text area. Did you pause the logcat on purpose? I'd also add that you might try to restart eclipse, and make sure that the nexus has debugging allowed. Short of that, I'm out of ideas at the moment...

Answer (score 0):

Check this image out:

[here](http://thiranjith.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/step4_selectingddms.png)

See how he has the 'W' selected. Change it to the 'V'

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with same problem for several days. I have jelly bean on my phone.

Thank you Revolutionair, it seems I got rid of the problem once I did the update for Android SDK, ADT, AVD manager.