# Why is LogCat showing all items as warnings (orange)?

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

Eclipse is acting strange. It shows every single log item as a warning (orange). Furthermore, each one's Time is '?:??', PID is '?', and Tag is also '?'.

Screenshot below

[image: LogCat, what the hell man?]

Comment: Hell, that's weird... have you tried to unplug your device or restart Eclipse?

Comment: Since I'm forced to restart Eclipse for various reasons quite often, I had tried that one, but now I tried both your suggestions. No luck.

Comment: Oh... the questionmark part looks remotely familiar to me. Do you know how to get into service mode on your phone? Wiping the cache can help in cases like that. Also turning off and on again debug mode on your phone could be worth a shot... But weird nevertheless

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your Eclipse or SDK seems to be outdated, just update it.

You are probably testing your app with an Android version (4.1??) which isn't fully supported by your current SDK version.

Comment: That just seems the solution, I still don't understand why the problem manifests in this way though. Also this question was apparently asked here before:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439821/debugging-issues-android-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the device is online and it is selected in the DDMS and this is the one you are installing your application on.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439821/debugging-issues-android-eclipse) - try to update you SDK !
In Eclipse go to 'Android SDK Manager' and try to update 'Android SDK Tools' & 'Android SDK Platform-tools'.
Note: It may ask you to update your ADT as well...

By the way, it's happend to me when I updated my android device to 4.1 Jelly Beans

Hope that helps,

Cheers!

Comment: Hahah, I am the one providing the answer for the question you linked to :) I did that after I got the answer here

Comment: Opps :) sorry about that, I didn't notice.. I didn't try to take credit from you! that's why I add the link to your answer - thank you again for the answer!