# Jelly Bean confusing LogCat

Tags: android, logcat, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I've recently just updated the firmware of my phone to Jelly Bean. I've noticed when viewing the LogCat in Eclipse, that I'm getting weird feedback.

Weird feedback being:

- Time is unknown
- pid is unknown
- tag is unknown (very irritating, because my filters wont work!)
- messages all in green color (very irritating, since errors are
  difficult to find in the log)

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to update your [Application Development Tools (ADT)](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) and [Software Development kit (SDK)](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) manager?

Comment: No I haven't updated my development tools. I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this question. Is more or less the same issue:

[Why is LogCat showing all items as warnings (orange)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494257/why-is-logcat-showing-all-items-as-warnings-orange)

I think the solution is related with your outdated SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps somebody did not like new jumping logcat and used old deprecated. It is not the option anymore. Old can't parse log file from jelly bean properly.

But there are good news, new logcat does not jump anymore :)

Comment: The scroll lock is simply a beautiful feature. ;)