# android crashing when creating file

Tags: java, android, file

I am working on an audio application, 
but it crashes when trying to create the PCM file, here the code:

```
public class RecordPCM {

public void record() {

    Log.d("mensaje","Recording testeo started");



    int frequency = 11025;
    //int channelConfiguration = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO;

    int channelConfiguration = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO; //cambiado por el de arriba por deprecado


    int audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/reverseme.pcm");




    // Delete any previous recording.
    if (file.exists()) {
    file.delete();
    Log.d("mensaje","file exists!!!");

    }


    // Create the new file.
    try {
    file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to create :::: " + file.toString());
    }

    try {
    // Create a DataOuputStream to write the audio data into the saved file.
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);

    // Create a new AudioRecord object to record the audio.
    int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(frequency, channelConfiguration, audioEncoding);
    AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, 
    frequency, channelConfiguration, 
    audioEncoding, bufferSize);

    short[] buffer = new short[bufferSize]; 
    audioRecord.startRecording();


    boolean isRecording = false; //metido para arreglar

    while (isRecording) {
    int bufferReadResult = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    for (int i = 0; i < bufferReadResult; i++)
    dos.writeShort(buffer[i]);
    }


    audioRecord.stop();
    dos.close();

    } catch (Throwable t) {
    Log.d("mensaje","Recording Failed");
    }

}

public void copio(){
    Log.d("mensaje","Recording testeo");

}
}
```

so when I call

> recordObject.record();

The app crashes with the error:

```
?:??: W/?(?): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
?:??: W/?(?): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
?:??: W/?(?):   at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3597)
?:??: W/?(?):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
?:??: W/?(?):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
?:??: W/?(?):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
?:??: W/?(?):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
?:??: W/?(?):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
?:??: W/?(?):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
?:??: W/?(?):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
?:??: W/?(?):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
?:??: W/?(?):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
?:??: W/?(?):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
?:??: W/?(?):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
?:??: W/?(?): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
?:??: W/?(?):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
?:??: W/?(?):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
?:??: W/?(?):   at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3592)
?:??: W/?(?):   ... 11 more
?:??: W/?(?): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to create :::: /storage/emulated/0/reverseme.pcm
?:??: W/?(?):   at com.hyper.reverspeech.RecordPCM.record(RecordPCM.java:48)
?:??: W/?(?):   at com.hyper.reverspeech.ReverSpeechActivity.buttonRecPressed(ReverSpeechActivity.java:20)
```

So

1. what is making my app crash,
2. Why is my logCat shown with ? question marks??,

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of your "crash" is that your application is throwing am `IllegalStateException` when it tries (and fails) to create the file.  Why you are getting an `IOException` is anyone's guess.  You are throwing away the evidence!  (Hint: use the `IllegalStateException` constructor that includes an exception argument ... and pass `e`)

The question marks in your logcat output could be explained by these:

- [Debugging Issues (Android Eclipse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439821/debugging-issues-android-eclipse)
- [Why is LogCat showing all items as warnings (orange)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494257/why-is-logcat-showing-all-items-as-warnings-orange)