# eclipse not displaying time in logcat for galaxy nexus only?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-logcat, nexus-s

I am using Galaxy nexus with Jelly bean and i have noticed that logcat does not display time . 
I also noticed that it does not apply filters for Galaxy Nexus . It also does not show the exceptions in red color .

```
?:??: W/?(?): [ 07-16 10:31:42.153   462:  462 D/PhoneStatusBar ]
?:??: W/?(?): disable: < expand icons alerts ticker system_info back home RECENT* clock >
?:??: W/?(?): [ 07-16 10:31:42.231   309:  341 V/LockPatternKeyguardView ]
?:??: W/?(?): Set visibility on com.android.internal.policy.impl.LockPatternKeyguardView$4@42bb3168 to 8388608
?:??: W/?(?): [ 07-16 10:31:42.231   462:  462 D/PhoneStatusBar ]
?:??: W/?(?): disable: < expand icons alerts ticker system_info BACK* HOME* RECENT CLOCK* >
?:??: W/?(?): [ 07-16 10:31:42.270   309:  311 D/dalvikvm ]
?:??: W/?(?): GC_CONCURRENT freed 521K, 17% free 25327K/30343K, paused 14ms+13ms, total 152ms
?:??: W/?(?): [ 07-16 10:31:42.302   309:  341 V/LockPatternKeyguardView ]
?:??: W/?(?): Set visibility on com.android.internal.policy.impl.LockPatternKeyguardView$4@42bb3168 to 8388608
```

It makes debugging very difficult. Please help me .

Comment: I use a Galaxy Nexus with Jelly Bean and don't experience these problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out . I updated my ADT version , since i did not have jellybean . Mainly you need to update your sdk tools too . Look into this question

[Debugging Issues (Android Eclipse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439821/debugging-issues-android-eclipse)