# android logcat does not display Time, PID etc

Tags: android, logcat

[image: screenshot] Can anyone help to fix the strange display of the logcat?

Comment: Close all your perspectives and open [this](http://www.openehealth.org/download/attachments/3211398/IPF-management-perspective-initial.PNG?version=3&modificationDate=1255422782000) one. Or, try to restart your Eclipse. It will be much better :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating your Eclipse and Android SDK will likely solve the problem.

[image]

For more info,refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439821/debugging-issues-android-eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

close your logcat and then again add it using show view or use deprecated logcat..